# Can I mount kitchen island countertop supports to the cabinet back panel?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, kitchen-island

I'm finishing up my kitchen island and have a 36" deep piece of laminate top. It overhangs 12" on the back of the two 33" wide base cabinets.

I know it is common practice to install L brackets to support the overhang, but that means the bracket is screwing into the thin particle wood backing the cabinets have. Is this sufficient? Is there a better way as Norm Abram would say?

I saw online some marble cantilever supports that work in a way that they run across the entire top of the cabinet base making it so the weight of that area counters the 12" overhang.  They require notching out the back of the base cabinet just enough so the bracket sits flush with the rest of the surface.  These seem both expensive and maybe not made for a laminate style countertop.

Answer (score 3):

Corbels are commonly used (as opposed to L-brackets), and they should work fine with your cabinet panel, assuming appropriate screws are used. Most of the force applied is in shear (up and down).

You could also install a sheet of 3/4" BC plywood onto your cabinet (nicer side down), and lay the laminate top onto that. The plywood should fit neatly inside the laminate top's edge lip, and it will provide more than enough strength for your small overhang while maintaining a floating appearance.

Comment: I like the plywood idea, would a single corbel in the middle be acceptable or is that too far a span? If it's in the middle of the span it can be secured to the frames of the two 33" cabinets as opposed to the backing of the cabinets (I've seen some really cheesy backing on cabinets)

Comment: If anchoring is really a concern, one corbel will probably do, though I'd expect some flex at the corners. Two would be better.

Comment: @isherwood This countertop I ordered actually already has filler installed. It's a very high quality countertop, I'd dare say the Cadillac for laminate and the material the laminate wraps.  My concern is that if I just glue and screw the top down to the base cabinets that the 12" overhanging the back side would not have enough support when someone leans on it.  I do not want to use a corbel block, but am open to the same pricipal in a metal L bracket. Something clean/crisp. I am thinking about just doing one on each end where the cabinet is reinforced.

Comment: @isherwood Here is the bracket: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07D5VN4JT/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1_1_1?smid=A3BZMBUYXMNP9R&psc=1

Comment: What is "a filler"? I'd be surprised if anyone could break off a 12" overhang with just laminated particle board, let alone something with another layer underneath. You probably don't need anything.

Comment: @isherwood So the countertop is a full 1.5" thick. It is wrapped on the end/lip so that it looks like slab of the material instead of seams showing, etc.  The filler is another layer of 3/4" particle board laminated with the top layer. So you know how on laminate tops there is a perimeter 2 or 3" wide particle board to get full thickness and to set on the base edge? Well this has a full 14 to 15" of the countertop filled solid where the overhang is. I thought this was filled solid for support bracket support, but perhaps it's meant for no brackets to be required?

Comment: Laminate top edges are 1-1/2" tall, typically, and they don't set on the base cabinet. They wrap over it. You'll have to ask your top manufacturer whether it's intended to be self-supporting. I don't know.